# Why are Zoom chat notification pop ups suppressed when in a Zoom meeting?

Tags: zoom-meeting

***TL;DR: Zoom Chat IM notifications are suppressed when in a Zoom Meeting***

Hopefully I can explain this...

Our company uses Zoom Business. I'm an admin, but not the owner. We use Zoom Chat as our main IM client and Zoom Meetings as our main meeting platform. I know the difference between in-meeting messaging and the main IM chat. I'm using Zoom 5.5.1 (upgraded today from 5.4.9) on Windows 10 with the **Use dual monitors feature** enabled. The gallery is on my laptop's screen (Windows monitor 1) where the camera is located and Zoom notifications appear. The shared screen is on another monitor (typically Windows monitor 2, but occasionally 3).

Zoom Chat notification pop-ups work as expected. I get all the notifications all the time - as long as I'm not in a meeting. As soon as I'm in a Zoom Meeting, the pop-ups and audio notification stop. Yes, the Zoom icon in my Notification Area gets a little red dot, but I'm full-screen in the meeting, so it's effectively invisible. Zoom Meeting chat notifications continue to work as expected. ***Bottom line: All Zoom Chat IM notifications are effectively suppressed when in a meeting, and that's a problem.***

In **Settings** > **Chat** I've disabled **Mute chat notifications while I am in a meeting or internal call**:
[image: Zoom Settings > Chat]

That's the only setting I'm aware of that affects this behaviour.
Why am I not seeing Zoom Chat IM notifications while in a Zoom Meeting? Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

In the Zoom client (5.5.2 shown), disable Settings > Share Screen > **Silence system notifications when sharing desktop** option:
[image: Disable Silence system notifications when sharing desktop option]

It's not in Settings > Chat, but it should be.